# Stream data from Browser to nodejs server using getUserMedia

Tags: node.js, stream, video-streaming, webrtc, sockjs

I'm trying to send data (video and audio) from Browser to a NodeJS server. On the client side, I'm using [getUserMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/NavigatorUserMedia.getUserMedia) to get a stream data and trying to send it over websockets via [SockJS](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client). Here is my code so far :

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        audio: true,
        video: true
    })
    .then(function(stream){
       // trying to send stream
       var video = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
       // send stream
       mystream.send(video.play());
    })
```

Where `mystream` is a `SockJS` instance.
My need is to persist the video as it is watched by a peer.

Has anyone ever sent a stream video to a server ? I'm out of ideas on this one. Any help/hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of researching, I just gave up and  used [Kurento](http://www.kurento.org/). It is well documented and there is some pretty interesting [examples involving NodeJS sample code](https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/6.9.0/tutorials/node/tutorial-one2many.html). I let the question open in case someone comes with a better idea.

Comment: Given that Kurento is open source, is it really giving up? As far as I can see Kurento is not a paid service - did you set it up yourself?

Comment: It is not completely giving up, but I would have prefered to twist this myself, at least to get a better understanding of how I can ths most of WebRTC.
I did set it up myself with the help of the tutorials : http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials.html

Comment: The links are broken :(